# Hadoop: I want to know Path to hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I want to open a file in Hadoop File System using a Java Program. I wanted to know how the path to HDFS look like and how to specify it in a Java Program?

Comment: An alternative is to pipe the output of running `hadoop fs -cat /file.txt` to your program.  Google "how to pipe output of program to java" or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the details of HDFS , its files , content in your java code use the Hadoop fs api.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html